# Laravel eloquent - prevent overriding values when joining tables

Tags: php, join, laravel, eloquent

### Ok, so i have following two models: `Account` and  `Role`

```
class Account extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'account';

  /* [...] */

  public function group() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Group');
  }
}
```

### and

```
class Role extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'role';

  public function accounts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Account');
  }

}
```

### and database tables: `account` and `role`

```
account
-------
id
name
role_id (nullable)

role
----
id
name
```

### And now the thing is:

I need to order `accounts` by `role.name` column. But after join (or leftJoin) values are overriden by those from second table. Here's some code:

```
$response = Account::with('role')->leftJoin('group', 'group.id', '=', 'account.group_id')->get();
```

After that values for `id` and `name` are incorrect in eloquent collections.

Also, i need the return to be eloquent type models as i'm returning back the response in JSON, where it is important that later in JS (after parsing JSON) i can do just `account.role.name`.

Changing names of fields in tables (like: id -> account_id, and: id -> role_id) would be an workaround, but that's not my case - need to have primary key named `id` for every table.

[edit]
Yep, so the question is simply: how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use 'select' like you would in a normal SQL query:

```
$response = Account::with('role')
    ->select('account.*')
    ->leftJoin('group', 'group.id', '=', 'account.group_id')
    ->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Comment: Ok, so it looks like all this eloquent magic has byte me. Anyway, you made my day. Thanks, answer accepted :)

Comment: This saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

Complementing the answer given by **@beech**, you can use alias inside your select clause, that way you can fetch only the specific keys you need e.g.

```
Account::with('role')
    ->select('account.id AS account_id', 'role.id AS role_id', 'account.name AS account_name', 'role.name AS role_name')
    ->leftJoin('group', 'group.id', '=', 'account.group_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all fields and avoid overwriting a particular table, add it as the last select table
`->select('group.*', 'account.*')`.

```php
$response = Account::with('role')
->select('group.*', 'account.*')
->leftJoin('group', 'group.id', '=', 'account.group_id')
->get();
```