# Eloquent join clause with polymorphism relationships overwrites id column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have four user types and all of them share same general user data table. And is using Eloquent Polymorphism so `$user->typeable() instanceof Talent`

Here's the code

```php
$this->query = Talent::query()->join(function($join){
    $join->on('users.typeable_id', '=', 'talents.id')->select('name');
});

if( $this->searchQuery )
{
    $this->query->orWhere(function($query){
        $query->whereLike('name', $this->searchQuery);
    });
}
```

But basically what happens is that wrong model is used on join. Because there can be like an **Admin** with same id as **Talent** and therefore two Users with identical `typeable_id` cause wrong **User** to be joined with **Talent** model.

```php
$talent->user()->name !== Talent::where('id', $talent->id)->join(function($join){
    $join->on('users.typeable_id', '=', 'talents.id');
})->first()->name; // true (that should not happen)
```

I tried to fix it explicitly saying that only **User** with `typeable_type` = \App\Models\Talent should be used.

My code:

```php
Talent::query()->join('users', function($join){
            $join->on('users.typeable_id', '=', 'talents.id')
                 ->on('users.typeable_type', 'like', DB::raw("'%Talent%'"))
                 ->select('name');
        });
```

That did the trick, but now when I try to add `$query->has('gallery')` and `gallery` being another relationship defined inside **Talent** class, the id is now overwritten with the id from users table.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018304/laravel-eloquent-prevent-overriding-values-when-joining-tables/47046355

Answer (score 0):

I needed to explicitly select the columns from the table I needed.

Answer taken from: [Laravel eloquent - prevent overriding values when joining tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018304/laravel-eloquent-prevent-overriding-values-when-joining-tables/47046355)

And here is what I ended up with

```php
$this->query = Talent::query()->leftJoin('users', function($join){
            $join->on('users.typeable_id', '=', 'talents.id')
                 ->on('users.typeable_type', 'like', DB::raw("'%Talent%'"))
                 ->select('name');
        })->select('talents.*'); // select the talents columns
```