# Applying global scope with join replaces main table column data with joined table column data having same column name in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-8, global-scope

I'm using a made up scenario, but facing similar issue.

I'm using Laravel 8 and have two **models** `Family & Centre`. Both containing common column name `id`.

In model `Family` I want to restrict families data based on centre of user logged in. For now I'm hardcoding it a dummy centre_id

Below is my `booted` function in `Family` model

```
protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('user_access', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->join('centres as c1', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('families.centre_id', '=', 'c1.id');
            });
        });
    }
```

Now when I query `Family` model in a controller, it joins with `Centre` model and the `id` column of `Family` gets replaced with `Centre` model `id` column.

For eg:

Family has one row with id -> 100 and centre_id = 1
Centre has one row with id -> 1 and name = 'Test'

After join in booted function, I get value 1 in `id` when I query `$family->id`. `$family` is an instance of `Family` model.

Expected result : 100

I don't want to use select in booted function as there are many aggregated function I'm using which will be causing issues.

Comment: For future(?) reference, this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018304/laravel-eloquent-prevent-overriding-values-when-joining-tables